# Strategy to have deleted objects in DB deleted in Core Data as well. [RestKit/Core Data]

Tags: ios, rest, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a REST service running on top of my application, which returns data to my iPad app. This app is built using RestKit to sync data in and out of the iPad. I have however a webapp running as well, which allows the users to delete some data.

The current problem that I have right now, is that whenever a user logs in into the iPad app, I run a query to get the data that was last_modified/added since his last login. This allows me to have faster/shorter queries. The only problem, is that if for example an object was deleted from the DB between his last two logins, the user will still see it in his iPad.

What strategy should I adopt to have this data in Core Data deleted as well? Should I just **not** delete object from my DB and have instead a BOOL that says "deleted" or not, and whenever I get the last_modified data via REST, this item will appear and I will just filter it out in the iPad?

I know RestKit has a way to delete orphans objects, but since I am syncing the "last_modified" data, I don't think it can be applied here.

Comment: Does the response contain all of the objects that you want to be in the DB (anything not in the response should be deleted)?

Comment: That's the problem. The response contains the objects that were added/updated since the last time the user logged in. So if for example Object 1 is in Core Data (with id==1), but it's Name changes since the last time the user logged in, it will be in the response. If it has changed, it will not be. If it is deleted, who can I know it?!

Comment: Then the server should really maintain a list of deletions and send those objects out too with a flag.

Comment: Perfect. I will probably adopt the same strategy... just have a list of the deleted objects, with a "deletion_date" field, and whenever I fetch the latest objects, I will fetch the "latest" deletion.

Comment: I created a list of objects that needs to be deleted from CoreData. So for I example, I return an array of IDS that corresponds to the Users I need to delete in CoreData. How can I do such mapping with RestKit?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment question:

> I created a list of objects that needs to be deleted from CoreData. So for I example, I return an array of IDS that corresponds to the Users I need to delete in CoreData. How can I do such mapping with RestKit?!

You should create a mapping to `NSMutableArray`. If your source data is a JSON array of strings then you will need to use a `nil` key path mapping in order to get the strings extracted into your destination array. See [this link](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#mapping-values-without-key-paths).

Comment: Okay good. But I can make RestKit try to delete the objects with the IDs that were just mapped? Should I just loop over the mapped NSArray and delete it myself or..?

Comment: You'll need to delete them yourself I think. RestKits methods of deleting aren't designed for your use case. You may be able to do something with a delete fetch request but I think it would be contrived.

Answer (score 0):

As Wain suggested, I will have a list of deleted objects in the Database with a "deleted_date" field. Whenever I will fetch the latest objects, I will also fetch the latest deleted objects back.